# Is it possible to have a function within a function?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to have a function within a function?

Something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Sub anim() Handles form2.Shown
            Me.Refresh()
            Do Until Me.Location.X = 350
                form2.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 1, 250)
                ' System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0.5)
            Loop
            form2.close()
        End Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your code is nonsensical. First, they are both Subs not functions.  The purpose of a function is to be able to invoke the resusable code it contains.  You will not be able to invoke `button1_Click.Anim` in part due to the params.  Next, there is no code in the anim which is not also part of Click (so they are the same).  What you PROBABLY want is to move `Anim` elsewhere so you can invoke it from this Click event or other clicks or because the code logic requires it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have a fully fledged nested function definition in VB.NET. The language does support multi-line lambda expressions which look a lot like nested functions:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
  Dim anim =
    Sub()
      Me.Refresh()
      ...
    End Sub
End Sub
```

There are some notable differences though:

- Cannot have a `Handles` clause.
- Cannot be `Implements` or `Overrides`.
- The instance of the lambda is named, not the `Sub` definition.
- In this case `anim` is actually a delegate and not a function.

Comment: so ? we can't do a sub with handles clause within a sub with handles clause ? im just a noobie in programming stuffs..

Comment: @yoyieyoyie you can't do a sub with handles inside another sub period.  The language is only setup to do handles clauses on real / outer function definitions

Comment: @yoyieyoyie: What are you trying to achieve? You need to start thinking in this direction. So your first question is **not what you can do**, or **how** you can do it, **but why** you need to do it. Once you have this clear, please update your question with more information.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is my child forms can be close by the buttons of the parent form..but i do it with some animation like it move from current location to off the screen then close form..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a function within a function, called lambda expressions.

In your case, however, it is unclear to me how it can be useful.

- [Lambda Expressions (Visual Basic) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)